# Help me find out why new and build method doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with my associations. I have n:n relation and everything going good but if i want initialize new object and then save it, it will by save with out associations. For example.

Models:

```
class User
  has_many :users_in_organizations, :class_name => 'UserInOrganization'
  has_many :organizations,:through => :users_in_organizations
end 

#Attributes [:user_id, :organization_id, :user_role]
class UserInOrganization 
   set_table_name 'users_in_organizations'
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization
  has_many :users_in_organizations, :class_name => 'UserInOrganization'
  has_many :users, :through => :users_in_organizations
end
```

this work fine but the problem is

```
org = User.first.organizations.new(:name => 'Test') #  new || build is the same
org.save # => true
User.first.organizations  # => []
Organization.all # => ['Test']
```

but if I use create then it works

```
org = User.first.organizations.create(:name => 'Test')
User.first.organizations  # => ['Test']
Organization.all # => ['Test']
```

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thank You :)

Comment: what is the behavior when you use `build` instead of `new`? It should work when you use `build`.

Comment: Does not work either. Only one what work is create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it working for `new` method, try this:

```
u = User.first
u.organizations.new :name => "new organozation"
u.save
u.organizations.size
=> 1
```

When you do `org = User.first.organizations.new :name => "test"` then you assign to `org` only organization and you save only that object. It doesn't save associated objects. That's why it doesn't work that way.

When you call `create` it saves created objects to db, using `new` or `build` doesn't save it to db.